# MVC5 webapplication on shared hosting giving a cookie decryption error on localhost works fine

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7, session-cookies

The below code is used to get the id stored in a cookie for a guest shopping cart. This code works fine on localhost but is giving me an error on shared hosting where I deployed my website.

```
public static class Func
{
    public static string SetCookie()
    {
        string key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


            string gid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var cookieText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(gid);
            var encryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(MachineKey.Protect(cookieText, key));
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Ecomm", encryptedValue);

                           myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            return gid;


    }

    public static UserShopCart GetCookie()
    {
        var usc = new UserShopCart();
        string key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";                  

            HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Ecomm"];
            if (myCookie != null)
            {
                if (myCookie.Value != null)
                {
                    var output = MachineKey.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(myCookie.Value), key);
                    usc.id = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);
                    return usc;
                }
                else
                {
                    usc.id = SetCookie();
                    return usc;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                usc.id=SetCookie();
                return usc;
            }
    }
}

public class UserShopCart {
    public string id;
    public string name;
}
```

Here is the snapshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Cookies are domain-bound. If you're sharing a domain with other unrelated sites, you're sharing cookies as well. Long and short: don't use shared hosting. You can get your own VPS for like $5/mo. Why would anyone use shared hosting at this point?

Comment: Chris Pratt as far as I know vps hosting for asp.net is starting from $10 to $12 with a limited size of hard disk space .suggest me if you know any better hosting with a better price rate .